# Particular permutations: derangement with additional limitations

Tags: permutations, derangements

A [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is a permutation of the elements of a set, such that no element appears in its original position.

Consider a set of 6 items, for instance, $ABCDEF$. There are 265 possible derangements (this is calculated as round($n!/e$)). For instance $FABCDE$

Let's coin a new term: 'poetic derangement'. For a derangement to be poetic, exactly 1 element must move exactly 1 position, exactly 2 elements must move exactly 2 positions, and exactly 3 elements must move exactly 3 positions.

For the set $ABCDEF$, there are two possible poetic derangements:

- $DAEFBC$ (Here, $A$ has moved one position, $E$ and $F$ have moved
  two positions, and $B$, $C$, $D$ have moved 3 positions).
- $DEABFC$ (Here, $F$ has moved one position, $A$ and $B$ have moved two positions, and $C$, $D$, $E$ have moved 3 postitions.

The poetic derangement concept applies to sets with a triangular number of elements. In general, if the number of elements of a set which move $x$ positions is defined as $Mx$, then a derangement is poetic when $Mx$ = $x$ for all $x$. That is, for a 10 element set:

- 1 element must move exactly 1 position
- 2 elements must move exactly 2 positions
- 3 elements must move exactly 3 positions
- 4 elements must move  exactly 4 positions

How many such poetic derangements are there? What is the general formula?

Comment: You missed two more, `BEFACD` and `CDFABE`. For $n=10$ there are $100$ poetic derangements. For $n=15$ and $n=21$ there are none, since the sum of the required shifts is odd whereas the sum of the actual shifts is always even. For $n=28$ there are lots (more than a million). [Here](https://gist.github.com/joriki/5b932d811c58f8f6a1d2a12bc3efcfd2)'s Java code to count them. The sequence $4,100,0$ doesn't appear in OEIS yet.

Comment: Thanks @joriki. That's exciting that it's not in OEIS!